# How to efficiently create a DataFrame from a list of dictionaries including nested lists and group by time

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary, nested

I am currently having trouble with efficiently creating a big dataframe from a nested dictionary. I know that a lot of people already asked this on SO but most of the time solutions use nested for-loops which in my case is extremely inefficient. Or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. I'm quite new to python and pandas, so any help would be much appreciated!

Anyway, my initial data structure looks something like this:

```
documents = [
               {
                  date: '2019-01-01', data: [
                                               {time: '08:32', boxId: 153}, 
                                               {time: '08:48', boxId: 323}, ...
                                            ]
               },
               {
                   date: '2019-01-02', data: [...]
               }
            ]
```

I need to aggregate the data for every boxId. This means that I have to count all entries per id and group them per hour. Like so:

```
time              153    152    323
2019-01-01 09:00  2.0    3.0    6.0
2019-01-01 10:00  7.0    5.0    4.0
2019-01-01 11:00  1.0    0.0    8.0
      .
      .
      .
2020-01-01 00:00  3.0    1.0    5.0
```

My current solution is extremely slow. This is how I'm doing it:

```
def format_to_df(documents, grouper_freq):
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
         dict({'date': doc['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}, **entry) 
         for doc in documents for entry in doc['data']
   )

   df['time'] = df[['date', 'time']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(' '.join(x)), axis=1)

   df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time', freq=grouper_freq), 'boxId'])
          .size()
          .reset_index()

   df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str)

   df = df.pivot(index='time', values=0, columns='boxId')
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
   return df.fillna(0)
```

This takes really long and produces around 3500 rows with my current data set. I'm guessing it's because I'm accessing `df['time']` in a bad way, right? Also I think the pivot is completely unnecessary but otherwise I'm getting

```
time              boxId  0
2019-01-01 09:00  323    5.0 
2019-01-01 10:00  153    2.0
2019-01-01 11:00  153    1.0
2019-01-01 11:00  152    3.0
      .
      .
      .
2020-01-01 00:00  323    8.0
```

which I don't want.

So how can I improve my code? How can I use pandas in a smart way?